# Why is arr[6] returning a null value in this code?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

```
ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>(),list2 = new ArrayList<String>(),list3= new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Hey");
list1.add("there");
list1.add(0, "knock");
list1.add(0, "knock");
list2.addAll(list1);
list3.add("Vasvi");
list3.add(0, "I'm");
list2.addAll(2, list3);
        
String[] arr= new String[8];
        
        
arr[6]="Who're";
arr[7]="You?";
System.out.println("arr[6]="+arr[6]);
        
arr=list2.toArray(arr);
System.out.println("arr[6]="+arr[6]);
        
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Output :

> arr[6]=Who're
> arr[6]=null
> knock
> knock
> I'm
> Vasvi
> Hey
> there
> null
> You?

As soon as the toArray(arr) method is called arr[6] becomes null. I'm not able to understand why?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the implementation of `toArray`?

Comment: From my understanding of toArray() this shouldn't have happened.

Comment: count the number of elements in `list2` right before the call to `toArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to look at the implementation; a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-) is sufficient:

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end of the collection is set to null.

Comment: If that was true why doesn't arr[7] also return null?

Comment: @VasviSood Because `arr[7]` is not “the element in the array immediately following the end of the collection”, and therefore nothing in the documentation says that it would also be set to `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the [implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) of `toArray(T[] a)` has the statements

```
if (a.length > size)
    a[size] = null;
```

That is the case here since `size` is 6 and `a.length` is 8 and therefore `a[6] = null` which is exactly what you observe.

The docs explain:

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end of the collection is set to `null`. (This is useful in determining the length of the list *only* if the caller knows that the list does not contain any null elements.)

Comment: If that was true why doesn't arr[7] also return null?

Comment: @VasviSood Because neither the docs nor the code says so, there is nothing to *"if that was true"* here, the outcome is clearly defined and coded.

Comment: @VasviSood you can argue that you would want it to behave differently or that you expect it to or that you would have done it differently but all that does not matter since it is not your decision to make. *"the element in the array immediately following the end of the collection is set to null"* and that is what is happening, end of story, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand how `toArray(T[] a)` works is to take a moment and read [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-):

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), **the element in the array immediately following the end of the list is set to null**. (This is useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller knows that the list does not contain any null elements.)

In your example array has 8 element and list only 6. Because of that 6th element is `null`.